# Angular Form submitting with an "undefined" result when attempting to sign into Firebase

Tags: angular, firebase-authentication, angularfire

I've been trying to figure out what is going on and have googled many times. One of the places I found was this post (https://www.positronx.io/create-user-with-email-password-in-firebase-and-angular/). I followed it as best as I could, but kept running into this error.

**Edit:Error message**

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'SignIn' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (SigninComponent.html:57)
    at handleEvent (core.js:19545)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.js:20639)
    at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (core.js:20342)
    at dispatchEvent (core.js:16994)
    at core.js:17441
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (platform-browser.js:993)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:423)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:14051)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:422)
View_SigninComponent_0 @ SigninComponent.html:56
proxyClass @ compiler.js:17129
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.DebugContext_.logError @ core.js:20601
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ErrorHandler.handleError @ core.js:12549
dispatchEvent @ core.js:16998
(anonymous) @ core.js:17441
(anonymous) @ platform-browser.js:993
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:423
onInvokeTask @ core.js:14051
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:422
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask @ zone.js:195
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask @ zone.js:498
invokeTask @ zone.js:1744
globalZoneAwareCallback @ zone.js:1770
SigninComponent.html:56 ERROR CONTEXT DebugContext_ {view: {…}, nodeIndex: 21, nodeDef: {…}, elDef: {…}, elView: {…}}
```

My Current code for my **signin.component.html** is:

```
    <!-- Default form contact -->
    <form class="text-center border border-light p-5" [formGroup]="contactForm">

      <p class="h4 mb-4">Contact us</p>

      <!-- Name -->
      <input type="text" formControlName="email" id="defaultContactFormName" mdbInput
        class="form-control mb-4" placeholder="Email">

      <!-- Email -->
      <input type="password" formControlName="password" id="defaultContactFormEmail" mdbInput
        class="form-control mb-4" placeholder="password">
  <button mdbBtn color="info" outline="true" block="true" class="z-depth-0 my-4 waves-effect"
    mdbWavesEffect type="submit" (click)="authenticationService.SignIn(email.value, password.value)" [disabled]="disabledSubmitButton">Send</button>

</form>
```

My Current code for **signin.component.ts** is:

```
import { Component, OnInit,HostListener } from '@angular/core';
import {AuthenticationService} from '../authentication.service';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-signin',
  templateUrl: './signin.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./signin.component.scss']
})
export class SigninComponent implements OnInit {

  contactForm: FormGroup;
disabledSubmitButton: boolean = true;
optionsSelect: Array<any>;

  @HostListener('input') oninput() {

  if (this.contactForm.valid) {
    this.disabledSubmitButton = false;
    }
  }

  constructor(public authservice:AuthenticationService,private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.contactForm = fb.group({
      'email': ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.email])],
      'password': ['', Validators.required],
      });
   }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

This component should be interacting with the **SignIn function for AngularFire** once it's submitted:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from "@angular/router";
import {AngularFireAuth} from '@angular/fire/auth'

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class AuthenticationService {

  constructor(
    public afAuth:AngularFireAuth,
    public router: Router
  ) { }

  // Sign in with email/password
  async SignIn(email:string, password:string) {
    debugger
    return await this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then((result) => {
         this.router.navigate(['/dashboards/v1']);
         console.log(result.user)
      }).catch((error) => {
        window.alert(error.message)
      })
  }
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Please copy the contents of errors and other text into the question itself instead of using screenshots.  It will be easier to read and search.  What you're showing now is very difficult to read.

Comment: In the component's constructor, you define your service as `authservice`, but in the HTML you try to call `authenticationService`.

Comment: @DougStevenson Thanks for letting me know that. I've updated the question to include the error in text form.

Comment: @JoelCarter Did fixing the mistake I mentioned solve it?

Comment: @JohnMontgomery Unfortunately no. But I did find a workaround that made things move along. Thanks for the help!